# Why strcmp doesn't work in Online GDB compiler?

Tags: c, sorting, gdb

Does Online GDB have any problems with string.h library?

```
void insertionSort( char *ptrArr[] )
{
    for( int i = 1; i < ROW; i++ )
    {
        char *temp = ptrArr[i];
        int j;
        for( j = i - 1; j >= 0 && (strcmp(temp, ptrArr[j]) == -1); j-- )
            ptrArr[j + 1] = ptrArr[j];
        ptrArr[j + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work in online GDB.
There are no changes in output array of pointers sorting.
But It works fine on my local compiler.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. It's possible that you have some kind of *undefined behavior* somewhere else, that manifests in this functions. Also, when you [edit] your question, also please explain more about the "doesn't work" part. *How* doesn't it work? What should happen? What actually happens?

Comment: Also, the name "Online **GDB**" implies that you have access to a debugger. Please use it to step through the code line by line to check what happens, while monitoring variables and their values. Splitting up complex expressions and saving their result to temporary variables also helps seeing what's going on.

Comment: GDB has nothing to do with the working of functions of the standard library. Do you mean the compiler you use in that online resource? -- Did you look up the documentation of `strcmp()` to learn more about the return value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison is wrong: instead of

```
(strcmp(temp, ptrArr[j]) == -1)
```

You should write

```
(strcmp(temp, ptrArr[j]) < 0)
```

Indeed, `strcmp` return a positive or negative value (or 0), not necessary -1 or 1 (or 0).

From man strcmp:

> The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your recommendation worked. It's been a long time from my last C program. I forgot some details.